# How do I submit event on f.collection_select, and change the content displayed, dependent on what is selected in the dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a webshop with products. I sell digital game accounts.
I have invented a dropdown menu, with f.collection_select, for the user to choose which server the account must belong to.
If the user selects a server, lets say "North America", I want the page to show the accounts which I have that belong to the server "North America". I have set up two models, the server model, this model just contains name:string, and the model has_many :accounts.

Next model I have is account.rb. This model stores all information in regards to account, and belongs_to :server.

I use this form for selection of server, in my views/accounts/index.html.erb
I can see that it works, and shows my servers, which I have created in the database.

```
  <%= form_with do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:server_ids, Server.all, :id, :name, remote: true) %>
  <% end %>
```

```
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :password
      t.string :BE
      t.integer :level
      t.integer :price
      t.references :server, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateServers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :servers do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is how the site looks atm with the dropdown:

[image: 1]

So here I have selected EUW server. When I change it to NA, I want the page to display the accounts I have in the association Server.find(name:"Europe West (EUW)".accounts

Here is a video, that shows what I am going for:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZUxS5oMMOw

Comment: first advice, don't use the displaying tag <%= %> for your logic: use <% %> for everything that you don't strictly need to display. 
Then I don't see enough of your code here but  you can have something like <%= f.collection_select(Server.where(:area = "north_america")) %> (I don't know what your Server model looks like so it's hard to help you further)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have added the server and account migration file for you to see, I understand that makes it easier helping me ! ^^
The <%= is necessary for the form to show up btw.

Comment: Upon server selection you can store the selection, I guess the server is gonna be selected by name, in which case you can go like: 
`f.collection_select(:server_ids, Server.find_by(name: "#{selected_name}").id), :id, :name, remote: true)`

Comment: The code snippet you posted there, gives me error when im loading page :S
Edited main: added video to show what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: Yes, I messed it up. I meant
`f.collection_select(:server_ids, Server.find_by(name: "#{selected_name}"), :id, :name, remote: true)`
And of course this may only work if the selected server name is in a string variable named selected_name.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but how would I store the selected field in the controller, so I can pass it in as #{selected_name} I am not sure how that should look :s

Comment: That depends on how the selection is passed to the controller, but you can store it in a variable like this: `selected_name = [...CHOICE...]`